# In modifying a file in a subfolder in a child theme, do I need all the files in that sub folder in my child?

Tags: child-theme

I am working with a Child theme and I needed to change a page in a subfolder in the theme. I uploaded the entire folder with all the enclosed files and modified the one file which worked. My question is... do I need all the files in the subfolder or just the one I modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you *should* only need the files that you are going to modify.

Technically you can move all the files from the parent-theme into the child-them. When you move only the files which need changing into the child-theme then it's a little simpler to keep track of the changes.

Also good to know when working with child-themes:
 `get_template_directory_uri()` will always grab the path to the parent theme. & `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will always point to the path of the active theme (whether it's parent or child)